# New to VS Pro 2022 but can't find rectangle and line in toolkit. How to install?

Tags: visual-studio

Haven't used VS in a while and recently installed VS Pro 2022 but can't find rectangle and line object to place on a form.  How to install?

Objects don't exist in toolkit.

Comment: Winforms, WPF, Maui, ...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.